# System.Windows.pdb not loaded - Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, backgroundworker

I just downloaded the Background worker sample from the website for reference and when i run the application it runs without any problem. The background task is executed normally and toast notifications are shown.

But the problem is after I changed the target version from Windows Phone 7.1 to Windows Phone 8, it didnt execute background tasks. It shows the Error `System.Windows.pdb not loaded`.

I didnt change the single piece of code in the project. I dontknow why this error occurs.. please help me..

This is the [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Background-Agent-Sample-02f0087b) I downloaded from the website.

This is the Call Stack 
`>  System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.JoltHelper.OnUnhandledException(object sender, System.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)   Unknown
        [Native to Managed Transition]

        [Managed to Native Transition]

        mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(System.Reflection.AssemblyName fileName, string codeBase, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly locationHint, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark, System.IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, bool throwOnFileNotFound, bool forIntrospection, bool suppressSecurityChecks) Unknown
    mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(System.Reflection.AssemblyName assemblyRef, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark, System.IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, bool throwOnFileNotFound, bool forIntrospection, bool suppressSecurityChecks) Unknown
    mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(string assemblyString, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark, System.IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, bool forIntrospection)    Unknown
    mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(string assemblyString, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark, bool forIntrospection)   Unknown
    mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(string assemblyString)  Unknown
    Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll!Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundAgentActivator.LoadEntryPointAssembly(string assemblyName) Unknown
    Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll!Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundAgentActivator.LoadAgent(string assemblyName, string typeName) Unknown
    Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll!Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundAgentActivator.Microsoft.Phone.IBackgroundAgentActivator.CreateBackgroundAgent(string assembly, string typeinfo)   Unknown
    Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll!Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundAgentDispatcher.AgentRequest.Invoke()  Unknown
    Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll!Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundAgentDispatcher.InvocationThread() Unknown
    mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object state) Unknown
    mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)    Unknown
    mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)    Unknown
    mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state)  Unknown
    mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() Unknown
    [Native to Managed Transition]`

Answer (score 0):

the pdb file is a symbols file used to step through code when debugging.

I am not ssure why you would want to step into the system.windows when debugging ... you may want to look in tools-> options and check that you are not tryign to step into microsoft code.

the problem is you are getting an exception and whlst the debugger is tryign to get to it it is meeting that exception.

There is no point stepping into that assembly as you cant change it - howveer maybe you want to look for the sake of it. Personally i wouldn't bother ;p

Comment: I just turned off the "Disable My code" in the tools->Options->Debugging, but this time it shows the exception "FileNotFound Exception was handled" - This call stack contains only external code.You need to turnoff Just my code and load symbols inorder to view source for this location.